# How to create httpd.conf on CentOS

Tags: centos, httpd.conf

I am getting this error message. I am running CentOS 5.2 with Apache 2. How would I re-create this file? Is there a command? The server was built from a VM image.

Starting httpd: fopen: No such file or directory
httpd: could not open document config file /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf
/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl startssl: httpd could not be started

Comment: if you 'cd' into those directories, are the files there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply uninstall and reinstall apache (using yum)